# Weight is NOT working as expected when i used it Notebook and Frame Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Below is the code . Here Page2 is second Tab of the UI (Check the UI Image) 
In second tab , i am creating the Frame and adding the label and Entry Box .

```
import tkinter as tk

from dicttoxml import dicttoxml
import xlrd


import GetValueFromExcel
from AppalyingXSLT import GenerateConfig
#import CreateXMLfromDict
from GetValueFromExcel import ExcelValue
from array import array
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, Button
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
CheckBoxSelection=[]
NameOfVariable=[]
KeyName=[]
SelectedCheckbox=[]
dict={}
frame_main = tk.Frame(root)
frame_main.grid(sticky='news')
canvas=tk.Canvas()

class UICreation():

    def __init__(self):
        print ("I m in __init__")
        self.nb=ttk.Notebook(frame_main)
        self.page1=ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.page2=ttk.Frame(self.nb)

    def tabcreation(self):
        print ("I M in Tab Creation")
        self.nb.add(self.page1,text="Select")
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.page1)
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.page1, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        f = tk.Frame(canvas)
        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=f, anchor="n")
        self.nb.grid(sticky=NW)
        print ("I M in checkBox")
        ListNumber=len(List_key)
        print (ListNumber)
        for value in range(0,ListNumber, 1):
             NameOfVariable= "checkBox" + str(value)
             CheckBoxSelection.append("var"+str(value))
             CheckBoxSelection[value]=IntVar()
             NameOfVariable = Checkbutton(f, text=str(List_key[value]),variable=CheckBoxSelection[value])
             Checkbutton()
             NameOfVariable.grid(sticky=NW)
             NameOfVariable.cget("text")
             KeyName.append(NameOfVariable.cget("text"))
        canvas.update()
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

    def addNew(self):
        self.nb.add(self.page2,text="Add")
        self.nb.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        page2frame=Frame(self.page2)
        page2frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=3)
        page2frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        lblentry = Label(page2frame, text="Entry Box:")
        lblentry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W')
        entrybx = Entry(page2frame)
        entrybx.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+W, columnspan=10)
        #codeName=tk.Label(page2frame,text="Name").grid(row=1,rowspan=2,pady=(10,10),sticky="NW")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui = UICreation()
    ui.tabcreation()
    ui.addNew()
```

[image: UI Image]

In above image , from the above code I am getting entry box only for some columns (As mentioned in "red" section)even if i try to extend .

Please let me know , how to extend it like i need which i have shown in the "Green Box"

Comment: Your example code is not testable. Please provide an example we can copy pastes and run. Secondly your title says weights are not working but your code does  not show any use of weights.

Comment: @Mike-SMT `page2frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` and I tried `page2frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=2)` . I have whole lot of code other tab. I have made the above code as a function and calling it from main function using by object

Comment: You still should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That said it looks like you are providing the weight on the wrong frame/window. The weight should not be in the `page2frame` but rather `self.page2`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT but I have frame inside the page2 correct . Will it still not work ?.can we give weight to tab?

Comment: Sorry let me clerify. You need to add a weight to page2 column 0 and to page2frame column 1.

Comment: In `self.nb=ttk.Notebook(frame_main)` what does `frame_main` refer 2. is this the root frame/window?

Comment: @Mike-SMT that's the main frame of my UI .. as explained I have two tabs ..I am hiding one tab in this post

Comment: I understand that however your code still is not testable. `main_frame` refers to nothing in your example.

Comment: @Mike-SMT posted full code

Comment: @Mike-SMT list key is something I m reading from other class.  For keeping check box in first tab that's page1

Comment: I updated my answer. It should work for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

From your updated question I can see that you need to put weight in column1 of page2.

`self.page2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`

Replace:

```
class UICreation():

    def __init__(self):
        print ("I m in __init__")
        self.nb=ttk.Notebook(frame_main)
        self.page1=ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.page2=ttk.Frame(self.nb)
```

With this:

```
class UICreation():

    def __init__(self):
        print ("I m in __init__")
        self.nb=ttk.Notebook(frame_main)
        self.page1=ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.page2=ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.page2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

I have updated your code to reflect a cleaner example that follows PEP8 better.

Let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class UICreation():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.nb=ttk.Notebook(master)
        self.page1=ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.page2=ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.page2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.check_box_election=[]
        self.name_of_variable=[]
        self.key_name=[]
        self.selected_checkbox=[]
        self.dict={}
        self.frame_main = tk.Frame(root)
        self.frame_main.grid(sticky='news')
        self.canvas=tk.Canvas()
        self.list_key = ["1", "2"]

    def tabcreation(self):
        self.nb.add(self.page1,text="Select")
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.page1)
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.page1, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        f = tk.Frame(canvas)
        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=f, anchor="n")
        self.nb.grid(sticky="nw")

        list_number = len(self.list_key)
        for value in range(0,list_number, 1):
            name_of_variable= "checkBox" + str(value)
            self.check_box_election.append("var"+str(value))
            self.check_box_election[value] = tk.IntVar()
            name_of_variable = tk.Checkbutton(f, text=str(self.list_key[value]),variable=self.check_box_election[value])
            name_of_variable.grid(sticky="nw")
            name_of_variable.cget("text")
            self.key_name.append(name_of_variable.cget("text"))
        canvas.update()
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

    def add_new(self):
        self.nb.add(self.page2,text="Add")
        page2frame = tk.Frame(self.page2)
        page2frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew', padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=3)
        page2frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        lblentry = tk.Label(page2frame, text="Entry Box:")
        lblentry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
        entrybx = tk.Entry(page2frame)
        entrybx.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", columnspan=10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    ui = UICreation(root)
    ui.tabcreation()
    ui.add_new()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Changed as you said , Added above the code completely . Still its not working. I am using Pycharm . Is there something i am still missing

Comment: This worked .. can I know what was prob with my code .. I saw changes ,but why was that changes ?

Comment: The main issue was where you were placing your weights. You needed the weight on page2 column zero and and page2frame column one. The cleanup was mostly style and import stuff. For example you were importing way 2 much for tkinter. All you need for just about anything is `import tkinter as tk` and `import tkinter.ttk as ttk`. Then you just call every widget you need with those prefixes. Example: `tk.Label()`, `ttk.Button()` and so on.

Comment: Great !! Thanks